# JFolder::create: Could not create directory Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using below PHP code here to create a particular folder if it didn't exist. I'm using joomla 2.5

```
$path = my/path/goes/here;
$folder_permissions = "0755";
$folder_permissions = octdec((int)$folder_permissions);
//create folder if not exists
if (!JFolder::exists($path)){
     JFolder::create($path, $folder_permissions);          
}
```

But this code throws below error

```
JFolder::create: Could not create directory
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Check your `var $log_path` and `var $tmp_path` path in configuration.php

Comment: is your ftp properly configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things I think might be causing the problem:

1. You forgot a `;` on the end of `octdec((int)$folder_permissions)`
2. Try removing the whole line `$folder_permissions = octdec((int)$folder_permissions)`

**Update:**
This is what I used to create a simple folder:

```
$destination = JPATH_SITE.'/'."modules/mod_login";
$folder_name = "new_folder";
JFolder::create($destination .'/'. $folder_name, 0755);
```

Comment: @Dasun - Ok...how did you define the path? using JPATH_SITE or JURI?

Comment: JPATH_SITE give '\' as the DS instead of '/'. What can I do? 
EG : D:\wamp\www\pro/components/com_jink/resources/models/4/

Comment: @Dasun - I have updated my answer again with what I used in my previous extension.

Answer (score 0):

What could the reason be?
Simple: The user that tries to create that directory doesn't have permission (or your Joomla is broken).

The user that runs the code is probably www-data (on most *nix/Apache). ALso 'nobody' or 'apache' are possible. 
If you have rootpermission try this:

1) become the webuser (eg www-data)

2) Jump to the directory my/path/goes/here

3) type: mkdir mynewdir

And you will probably find out that the user doesn't have sufficient permissions to do so.

Comment: did everyday you said. but still no luck

Comment: no luck? I wasn't posting a solution, I was telling you how to test your action by hand/commandprompt. Your code fails: You don't have permission: so find out why that is. DOes the user have write permissions in the directory? What did you check?

Answer (score 0):

edit your `configuration.php` file under Joomla home direcory, change:

From:

```
var $tmp_path = '/home/public_html/your_name/tmp';
```

To:

```
var $tmp_path = 'tmp';
```

and `tmp` should have 777 permission